# Ruby rest-client returning 401 while curl command works

Tags: ruby, curl, get, http-status-code-401, rest-client

I have a working curl command which returns exactly what I want, bunch of JSON:

```
curl -D- -u username:password -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://stash.address.net/rest/api/1.0/projects/FOOBAR/repos\?limit\=1000
```

And I need to transform it into RestClient::Request, but I am still getting 401 back:

```
RestClient::Request.execute(
    method: :get,
    headers: {
        content_type: 'application/json'
    },
    username: 'username',
    password: 'password',
    url: 'https://stash.address.net/rest/api/1.0/projects/FOOBAR/repos',
    params: {
        limit: '1000'
    },
    verify_ssl: false
)
```

Did I forget something? Is there something missing from my request? Isn't it exactly same as the curl command above?

Comment: Please DO NOT use `verify_ssl: false` or you are essentially invalidating the whole purpose of https.

Comment: Not using that causes error: "SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (RestClient::SSLCertificateNotVerified)" thats why I added it.

Comment: then you have another problem to resolve. You are missing some certificates or the ones you have are outdated. Don't take the easy way, take the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the documentation](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client) I don't see any mention of the `username` and `params` options. They suggest to interpolate the value in the URL.

```
RestClient.get 'https://username:password@stash.address.net/rest/api/1.0/projects/FOOBAR/repos', { accept: :json, params: { limit: 1000 }}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you very much, appreciate it!

Comment: Is that space after `username` is intentional?